# Periodically scan for bluetooth devices on android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wonder how to scan periodically for bluetooth devices, even when app is closed? I tried to register receiver and tried not to unregister in `onDestroy()` method, with hope that it will countinue working in background.
But when i close the app it sends an error:

`Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?`

And there are no more scanning. So, please, can someone tell me how to do this? Maybe it has to do something with services? Send me on the right path :)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create an Intent service that responds to the intent that you have in your filter (I apologize I do not remember the intent). This service would run each time that intent is broadcast.

Here are the docs to create an Intent Service

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Such as this intent filters?
`BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED,
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND,
BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED,
BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHE`

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to scan? If you're not using it, I believe you should be using the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) class. It will allow you to continuously perform a task without the app needing to be open. There are plenty of tutorials out there.